# How can I ask this "am I right question": any ideas?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

My philosophy acquaintances are busy and or bored

> 1. When the future now will end the past now will not (FN =/= PN)
> 2. The present now will have ended when some past now will end (PN -> TN)
> 3. When the future now will end the present now will not have
>    ended (FN =/= TN)

How can I ask this question without it being poorly received and closed? I'm not saying I'm right: I want to know if I might be (so I'm not pushing a personal philosophy).

What about: how would you phrase this in temporal logic (and is it wrong)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like at least part of your question is "How to symbolize this concept in modal logic" which is definitely a common question-pattern here.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the reply. The second assumption isn't very appealing so IDC

Comment: Exactly what I talked about. Maybe the community could edit the question for first questioners and those with low reps? Just as SE requires? Or construe them as broadly to answer as it was necessary for you to understand and then advice how to reformulate it to be understood?